# A specific htaccess inquiry

Tags: php, .htaccess

After a bit of research I think its better if I ask for help to a specific problem, because I think if I am to learn the skills needed, I'd be taking on another language, and I can't get into the details of htaccess and regular expression at the moment, hopefully someday.

What I have now in URL is (localhost/site/controller/function/$arg1)

What information do I need to place into the htaccess so the controller and function isn't displayed. But the end result is (localhost/site/$arg1).

Comment: Everything you need is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever

Comment: You have not shown any effort in trying to actually implement a solution yourself.

Comment: Read @MikeBrant's comment again. "You have not *shown* any effort". Yes, because there is no code in the post, it has not been *shown*.

Comment: @venichhe Yes we would rather you learn how to learn. Research, try, ask questions when you run into problems you see no resolution to.  Most importantly when asking those questions, make sure you can explain what you have tried, why you think it didn't work, etc. That way we as givers of advice don;t have to start from square one or give you information that you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this doesn't really make sense. As stated in the comments, you can use mod_rewrite to send your shortened URLs to the controller, but controller and function need to be static. So having a separate function doesn't really help, controller should be enough.

One thing you could do is selecting the RewriteRules in your .htaccess depending on the $arg1 using for example RewriteCond. That way you could send different URLs to different controllers. It depends on your URL structure if this is feasible.